# Yii2 - Ошибка 403 и 400

Tags: yii2, отладка

Пытаюсь на хостинге зайти в debug выдает ошибку:

> Forbidden (#403)
>   You are not allowed to access this page.

Тоже самое с gii, на локальной машине такого нет.

И второе - все формы в backend при отправке выдают:

> Bad Request (#400)
>   Не удалось проверить переданные данные.

На локальной машине эта ошибка есть. debug показывает что csrf передается, 
вот он:

> _csrf     'QXNaWk4wVlMjEjU4Clo/JjIXGx8lAj8YFxFiOH1fPjw4MRQZY1YxFw==

Помогите найти ошибку или хотя бы в каком направлении искать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте в **config/web.php** следующие строки:

```
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
     'class'      => 'yii\debug\Module',
     'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
];
```

Добавив строку с **allowedIPs** вы допускаем доступ с любого IP. Данное правило относится и к **Gii**. Советую не использовать **debug/gii** на продакшне.

Comment: у меня в backend/config/main-local.php стоит так   $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
для чего allowedIPs ?

Comment: allowedIPs помогло с дебагом, а с csrf как протестить ?

Comment: Если честно, я не понял насчет csrf. Вам нужно csrf значение на хостинге отловить?

Comment: У меняч не рабоатет не одна форма в backend выдает вот это "Bad Request (#400) Не удалось проверить переданные данные" а csrf передается вот не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />  --- Попробуйте вставить во вьюшку формы. Если сработает, я дополню ответ. Примерно я понял от чего

Comment: "debug показывает что csrf передается вот он _csrf   'QXNaWk4wVlMjEjU4Clo/JjIXGx8lAj8YFxFiOH1fPjw4MRQZY1YxFw==' " вот полностью как звучал вопрос 
 И второе все формы в backend при отправке выдают Bad Request (#400) Не удалось проверить переданные данные. на локальной машине эта ошибка есть. debug показывает что csrf передается вот он _csrf   'QXNaWk4wVlMjEjU4Clo/JjIXGx8lAj8YFxFiOH1fPjw4MRQZY1YxFw=='

Comment: Вы опробовали выше стоящий коммент?

Comment: "Bad Request (#400)Не удалось проверить переданные данные."  там собака глубже порылась

Comment: Используете layout? Если да, то в секцию head добавьте <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

Comment: есть она там, а как это можно сделать "убедитесь, что проверяется отосланный вами токен с другим токеном"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42887/discussion-between-urmuz-tagizade-and-sergalas).